# Asymptotics of logarithm: $\frac{1}{n}\ln(a+o(1)) = \frac{1}{n}\ln(a)+o(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, notation, logarithms, asymptotics

[image]

I am having problems with the use of the little oh notation my professor is adopting in the solutions to some exercises.

As an example I do not understand why 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\ln(a+o(1)) = \frac{1}{n}\ln(a)+o(\frac{1}{n}).
$$
It seems to me that the definition of little oh is not verified because 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n}\ln(a+o(1)) - \frac{1}{n}\ln(a))}{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
 does not equal $0$, I remain with 
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(a+o(1)) - \ln(a))
$$
that I do not know exactly how to treat but it seems to me it can't equal $0$ because $o(1)$ is an unknown function that does not depend on $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $o(h)$ is not a specific function. In a limit settings, it is usually used to denote a small quantity *compared to* the quantity $h$.

In this given settings, one is working with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$. Then one should take $o(1)$ as some quantity that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{o(\color{red}{1})}{\color{red}{1}}=0,$$
and $o(\frac1n)$ some (other) quantity satisfying
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{o(\color{blue}{\frac1n})}{\color{blue}{\frac1n}}=0.$$
Inparticular, $$\frac{1}{n}o(1)=o(\frac1n).$$

---

Back to your examples, the facts that $\ln$ is a continuous function and that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}o(1)=0$ imply
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(a+o(1))=\ln a,$$
which is equivalent to the statement

> If $x_n\to 0$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln(a+x_n)=\ln a.$

and is equivalent to

> $$\ln(a+o(1))-\ln a=o(1).$$

---

Now can you work out the meaning of each statement in the proof?

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try, and if I have problems I will write back tomorrow.

Comment: I am having some problems figuring out why $exp((1/n)ln(a)+o(1/n)) = 1 + (1/n)lna + o(1/n)$

Comment: $e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\dots$. Now what if you replace $x=\frac1n\ln a+o(\frac1n)$?